# In cordova, how to navigate to another html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am currently working on a Cordova project in Visual Studio. In this project, I am trying building 2 html pages, let me call them first.html and second.html.

In the first.html, I want to add a link to second.html, which allows me to navigate to second.html. I tried 2 ways.

1. window.location

   ```
   window.location = "second.html"
   ```
2. tag

   ```
   <a href=“second.html”></a>
   ```

As a result, they both caused an error saying "Exception occurred
Message: Exception: Cannot redefine property: org".

Can anyone tell me how to navigate to a new page properly?

Comment: By the way, I am using ripple to test my app.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280351/how-navigate-one-page-to-another-page-in-android-phonegap

Comment: Are the typographical quotes `<a href=“second.html”></a>` ok?

Comment: The quotes should be ok. In fact, I have tried the solution mentioned by eugen, but it still gives me the save error.

Comment: I don't know for sure.but try adding `<a data-ajax="false" href=“second.html”></a> `  does it working ?

Comment: It shows     Cannot GET /%E2%80%9Csecond.html%E2%80%9D

Comment: You will have a easier time by orders of magnitude if you try to not do all this with just basic javascript+html.

Instead, try using Ionic (which uses AngularJS). And use the routing (AngularUI Router) to do your page transitions. Keeps it all SPA so you don't have to track various window instances in cordova and your page transitions will look clean instead of popping into existence instantly.

Answer (score 14):

You can navigate to another page using window.location.href. An example is shown below

```
    function(){ window.location.href = "second.html";}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this it work's for me

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>My PhoneGap</title>

              <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>      
              <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

                 function onLoad()
                 {
                      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
                 }

                 function onDeviceReady()
                 {
                      // navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");
                 }

                 function callAnothePage()
                 {
                    window.location = "test.html";
                 }

              </script>

      </head>

      <body onload="onLoad();">
            <h1>Welcome to PhoneGap</h1>
            <h2>Edit assets/www/index.html</h2>
            <button name="buttonClick" onclick="callAnothePage()">Click Me!</button>
      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below line to navigate one page to another page.

```
 $('#yourelement').click(function(){      
    window.location.assign('name_of_page.html');
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 window.open("second.html");
```

window.open opens a new window/tab with the selected URL, while the mentioned method in the question redirects the current page to the selected URL.